# Converting floating point IIR to fixed point arithmetic, given its difference equation

Tags: lowpass-filter, infinite-impulse-response, fixed-point

Is there some general way to perform the task given in the question? I have a filter given as follows:

```
Tdouble MoogVCF::run(double input, double fc, double res)
{
  double f = fc * 1.16;
  double fb = res * (1.0 - 0.15 * f * f);
  input -= out4 * fb;
  input *= 0.35013 * (f*f)*(f*f);
  out1 = input + 0.3 * in1 + (1 - f) * out1; // Pole 1
  in1  = input;
  out2 = out1 + 0.3 * in2 + (1 - f) * out2;  // Pole 2
  in2  = out1;
  out3 = out2 + 0.3 * in3 + (1 - f) * out3;  // Pole 3
  in3  = out2;
  out4 = out3 + 0.3 * in4 + (1 - f) * out4;  // Pole 4
  in4  = out3;
  return out4;
}
```

It's a 4th order IIR low pass filter which works in a feedback loop that generates a nice resonance. It sounds great, but my only problem is that my current CPU is too slow to handle it. It has no FPU and floating point operations take approx. 10x more cycles. I was thinking about converting it into fixed point arithmetic but after long time spent over a piece of paper and calculator I just gave up. Nothing seems to work. Do you know of any method with which I could convert the coefficients and add some bitshifts to make it a fixed point arithmetic filter?

I have 16bit DAC so the samples I process are 16 bit signed but the CPU is 32 bit so the filter can operate on 32bit integers.

Comment: Does your CPU include a fixed-point multiplier? I've used that, you need to substitute your C products by some assembly code.

Comment: It's Atmel SAM3x8E based on ARM Cortex M4. I think it should have it. Regardless - I'm looking for some general conversion rule for this. I was trying to premultiply the coefficients by bitshifting and then shifting back, but it's not so trivial and it's easy to make mistake. Is there some program that could do that for me?

Comment: you might want to first model your 4-pole Moog (with *"regeneration"*) as an **analog** filter, find out where the poles and zeros (on the $s$-plane) are, then use a method like the bilinear transform to make it into a digital filter with poles and zeros in the $z$-plane.

then you want to consider **how** fixed-point mathematics is done, in general, in a computer.  [lotsa discussion about that.](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse467/08au/labs/l5/fp.pdf)

Comment: Does your compiler support 16 bit short floats?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it doesn't :( Or at least I'm not aware of it. The whole board is Arduino Due and it has SAM3x8E microcontroller based on ARM Cortex M-3

Comment: Does f change every time you call the routine?

Comment: Sampling frequency is constant (I'm writing to DAC on interrupts) unless the load is so high it takes longer than interrupt clock to calculate and write sample.

Comment: First you have to determine the input range (and resolution).  Then multiply your coefficients to whole/integer numbers.  Fitting the scaling to the accommodate the input.  You can talk about "fixed point" but what 
 you are really dealing with are integers.  Speaking from experience I can say you had better simulate any design on a computer model over all operating conditions/inputs.  Making a simulation (and make sure it is typed as integers) will save you headaches in troubleshooting and maintenance.  Which you will probably have.  Can't find a low-res floating points routine instead.